# Installing Windows driver

Tags: windows, drivers, bluetooth

I need to install Windows driver instead of the Bluetooth driver installed on my computer by the laptop OEM. However, when I tried to uninstall my Bluetooth driver, Windows automatically reinstalls the driver that came with the laptop. Do you know if it's possible to achieve what I want to do easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the related .inf file in c:\windows\inf and move it to another directory.
2. Remove the device in device manager
3. Reboot

If you have moved the good one the default windows drivers will reinstall
(It could be have more than one .inf file to move if they are more than one drivers which was installed...)

Comment: Found out that I no longer need to do what I thought I need to do. I got the right drivers after all to work with the certain software I have.